# how to change background color of selected item in a listbox programmatically?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I am trying to change background-color of selected item of a listbox. it changes background-color but next time if I select another item, then background-color of previous selected item should set to null or default.

Listbox name is lstContacts.

private void lstContacts_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

```
lstContacts.ClearValue(ListBox.BackgroundProperty);//its not working   
 ListBoxItem item = lstContacts.ItemContainer.ContainerFromItem(lstContacts.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: I am facing same issue, did you got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 3):

Make use of the index of the item

```
var item = ListBox_Main.Items[0] as ListBoxItem ;
item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0))
```

Comment: I am facing problem to reset the background color of previously selected item.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Reset the whole list view background color before changing the background color of another item.

```
lstContacts.Background = new SolidColorBrush("your original color here");
```

Then proceed as

```
ListBoxItem item = lstContacts.ItemContainer.ContainerFromItem(lstContacts.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Answer (score 0):

Selected items already have background color set whenever you select it, either programmatically or by tapping on item.

How do you *set* the background color for the selected item? Have you changed the `ControlTemplate` for your `ListBox`?

Comment: Read the question very carefully. I am facing problem to reset the background color of previously selected item.

Comment: I get that, but what was its color? The default one or have you changed that one too?